# Using Conky execpi variable with Bash conditional statement

Tags: linux, bash, conky

I'm trying to write a simple "pinger" script which will periodically try to reach given IP address and output a colored message with information if it is available or not.

I face the problem in which I can't set custom color inside Bash conditional statement. The Bash code has been inserted into *execpi* variable. Every time when I try to run *Conky* I get Bash error *sh: 1: Bad substitution*.

Conky TEXT section:

```
TEXT
${color grey}Module_1: ${color}: ${execpi 10 if ping -c 1 -W 2 192.168.1.1 > /dev/null; then echo ${color green}"Success"${color}; else echo ${color red}"Failed"${color}; fi} | ${color grey}Module_2: ${color} ${execpi 10 if ping -c 1 -W 2 192.168.1.2 > /dev/null; then echo ${color green}"Success"${color}; else echo ${color red}"Failed"${color}; fi}
```

Should the `${color}` variables be placed in different way?

Comment: You should post yourself the answer to your question, and then you can mark it as **answered** (by accepting your answer), which is the equivalent here of closing the thread. It is indeed useful for future visitors. It's an encouraged practice around here : you did find the relevant knowledge to solve the problem and others would like to know it :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys from https://ubuntuforums.org help me out. The issue was not-escaped dollar signs inside Bash conditional expresion. Link to my thread and answers: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357244. Topic can be closed.